# Bazel remote cache query tools

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to debug why my bazel remote cache is full of misses.  I don't want to try describing my whole setup here, so I'm not asking for a final solution.  I am asking for ways to get visibility into the misses.

Ideally, I'd pass a flag to my bazel build command and it'd dump all cache queries into a log file along with whether they were hits or misses, and then I'd run some command and get a dump of all the queries that would have been hits.

Do that flag and command exist?  If not, is there something kind of like it?

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs at [Debugging Remote Cache Hits for Remote Execution](https://bazel.build/docs/remote-execution-caching-debug), you can compare the execution logs between two builds to understand differences in cache keys.

```
# first build
$ bazel clean
$ bazel ... build ... --execution_log_binary_file=/tmp/exec1.log
```

```
# second build
$ bazel clean
$ bazel ... build ... --execution_log_binary_file=/tmp/exec2.log
```

Then build the `execlog` parser from Bazel's source tree, and diff its outputs:

```
bazel-bin/src/tools/execlog/parser \
  --log_path=/tmp/exec1.log \
  --log_path=/tmp/exec2.log \
  --output_path=/tmp/exec1.log.txt \
  --output_path=/tmp/exec2.log.txt
```